# Usar variable de PHP en Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Estoy extrayendo datos de mi base de datos en una función de PHP. 
Quiero usar estos datos en mi archivo .tpl.

Para transformar la variable de php, con los datos de la base de datos a variable Smarty uso el siguiente código:

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$barraavisos_message = Configuration::get('BARRAAVISOS_MESSAGE');
$smarty->assign('mensaje', $barraavisos_message);

return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/widget/aviso.tpl');
```

Extraigo los datos en $barraavisos_message y con "assign" lo tranformo en variable Smarty con el nombre de mensaje($mensaje).
Luego para hago el return para renderizar en la vista.

En la vista simplemente hago lo siguiente:

```
<p>{$mensaje}</p>
```

Haciendo esto me da el error: Notice: ContextErrorException 
Undefined index: mensaje

He probado también de cambiar la linea del "return" a:

```
return $smarty->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/widget/aviso.tpl');
```

Y en este caso no me da error, pero me muestra el todo el código de mi archivo .php como texto, en vez del contenido de la variable.
No se donde estoy fallando...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo,

He cambiado la manera de asignar la variable a Smarty.
El código entero quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$barraavisos_message = Configuration::get('BARRAAVISOS_MESSAGE');
$this->context->smarty->assign('mensaje', $barraavisos_message);
return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/widget/aviso.tpl');
```

Con la segunda linea no hace falta crear la variable nueva Smarty y posteriormente asignar.